Kid finds a meteorite in the woods
I saw this movie in the early 80's on a local show that showed B-movies.  
I believe it was in color but it could have been in B&W.  
All I remember is that a kid finds a meteorite while out in the country woods.  When he gets back home, he puts it in a metal bath/washtub filled with water.  I believe it reacts with the water and becomes some kind of creature.  
If not that, it does something to the people who touch it.  I don't remember what happens after that.  
I don't know if the boy was the main character or just the boy who finds the rock that starts all the trouble and the main character is someone else.  
I'm pretty sure it isn't The Alien Dead, Monolith Monsters, They Came From Outer Space or Enemy from Space unless anyone remembers a scene like I described in any of them.  

In fact there IS such a scene in The Monolith Monsters (1957) except that it's a little girl not a boy.
Wikipedia

The Monolith Monsters tells the story of a large meteorite that crashes in a Southern California desert and explodes into hundreds of black fragments with strange properties. When those fragments are exposed to water, they grow very large and tall. The fragments also begin to slowly petrify some of the inhabitants of a nearby small town. 



Dave's girlfriend, teacher Cathy Barrett (Lola Albright), takes her students on a desert field trip; young Ginny Simpson (Linda Scheley) pockets a piece of the black meteorite rock, later washing it in a large tub outside her family's farmhouse.

The whole thing can be seen at DailyMotion at the 15:00 mark.
http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x22numj_monolith-monsters_shortfilms

